# How to get rid of SLF4J bindings in springboot project

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, splunk

Following the other answers I did exclude this, but I started getting  `ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender http java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:`

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
         </dependency>
```

I need to fix the SLF4J bindings as it is preventing my Logs to go to Splunk :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic- 
      1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl- 
      2.11.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings  for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your dependency tree with maven command:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

You will find there the dependency which provides existing SL4J binding. Then just change the exclusion to this one.

More information here: [Spring Boot: multiple SLF4J bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071002/spring-boot-multiple-slf4j-bindings/56754357)